# Does socket not have a EOF character unless the write socket close?

Tags: ruby, sockets

the process blocked at the `established` even after client socket write something and manually flush it unless the client socket close

```
server = TCPServer.new 2000 # a simple socket server                                                     

socket = server.accept                                                          

puts "socket established"                                                   
msg = socket.read                                                         
puts "type: #{msg.class} content: #{msg}"                                                                                                       

socket.close
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no 'EOF character' in sockets programming.
2. End of *stream* occurs when the peer closes the connection. It is signalled to the application by `read()` returning various API-dependent values.